# Are there any known file dispensing algorithms?

Tags: algorithms

I wish to know if there are any known algorithms for dispensing a list of files for a specified maximum directory size (disc size for example), while attempting to keep output directories size close to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the classic [bin-packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem).

It is classic because it can be applied to so many tasks that we'd like to optimize but it is computationally NP-hard.